# passing session data in codeigniter member site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a member login site where i am passing username in form like this

```
echo form_hidden('a_username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
```

what i found is user can alter names using firebug in hidden fields , what is the best way to send sesion data in database table ?

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best way to send sesion data in database table

Keep session-data serverside, so the client can't alter it. Never trust user input. You only need to store some kind of session ID, and lookup the data you need on the serverside.

Comment: so should i pass it via controller or model instead ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please update the main question with code that uses the session variables to clarify what you mean.